# Why does Python's iter() on a mapping return iterkeys() instead of iteritems()?

Tags: python, mapping, iteration

It seems like if you want to get the keys of a mapping, you ask for them; otherwise, give me the *whole* mapping (constituted by a set of key-value pairs). Is there a historical reason for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-September/010209.html) for a discussion on the reasons behind this behavior (including that Guido likes it, and it's [not likely to change](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-September/010222.html)).